# How to send json response with property with markup based on React as a stream?

Tags: javascript, express, stream

I use Express for creating HTTP-server.

In my case i need to send JSON with property "markup" that contains HTML based on React node.

Answer looks like this:

```json
{
  "markup": "<div>Some markup here</div>"
}
```

I want to render React to stream and send json as a stream too if it is possible.

How can i do this?